# Jquery .ajax method="post" but $_POST empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post"
    , url: "save.php"
    , data: "id=453&action=test" 
    , beforeSend: function(){

    } 
    , complete: function(){ 
    }  
    , success: function(html){ 
        $("#mydiv").append(html);        
    }
});
```

I have set method type as post but in Save.php I just get values either in `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` but not in `$_POST`.

My form looks like:

```
<form method="post" id="myform" action="save.php">
```

It was not working, looked around here and on Google, tried adding `enctype`

```
<form method="post" id="myform" action="save.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

but still `$_POST` empty?

How do I make it work?

Comment: Just had a similar problem using jQuery's ajaxForm plugin. i resolved it by ensuring that each input element had a 'name' attribute. Mine matched the ID selector, but this may not be necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `method: "post"` you need to use `type: "POST"`

So this should work without any alterations to your form  HTML:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    , url: "save.php"
    , data: "id=453&action=test" 
    , beforeSend: function(){

    } 
    , complete: function(){ 
    }  
    , success: function(html){ 
        $("#mydiv").append(html);        
    }
});
```

Not sure why it doesn't work but this works for me:

**save.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

**file.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('input').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST"
                    , url: "save.php"
                    , data: "id=453&action=test" 
                    , beforeSend: function(){

                    } 
                    , complete: function(){ 
                    }  
                    , success: function(html){ 
                        alert(html);        
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main"><input type="button" value="Click me"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your error must lie somewhere else.

Comment: @Wbdvlpr: open firebug console and check requests being sent. You can see what method it uses (get/post) and what parameters being sent to which url. Then go from there.

Comment: But I get values in $_GET and $_REQUEST .. but not in the $_POST .. any idea how to check if "somewhere else" is wrong??

Comment: You aren't doing cross domain requests, are you?

Comment: btw there is a good plugin that automatically gets all fields values from the form and submits it via ajax: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm

Comment: no its on the same domain .. one thing I haven't mentioned is this form is in a dialog window

Comment: @serg555: thanks for the link .. everything works fine except this POST so I dont think I need to use that plugin.

Comment: I don't understand though how this problem is related to a form. Where your ajax is being called? Maybe it is not called at all and you are just submitting a form itself instead of doing ajax call?

Comment: @serg555 .. checked in firebug console .. when I click the submit button it sends a GET request. Not sure why it does so.

Comment: Are you sure that it is ajax call that sending this request, not form itself? Try it without a form, just use a link or a button like in this answer. Maybe your ajax is not being called at all.

Comment: In the above example, the values are hardcoded but I am fetching values from FORM using serialize method.

Comment: Yes I am sure its ajax as in save.php i dont send page_header and footer when its an ajax request. Also on request completion I update (appendTo) html of dialog window.

Comment: Ok I give up then :p I've had some issues with ajax posts before but they were related to cross domain stuff.

Comment: @serg555 - thanks a lot for your efforts .. its a bit strange as if I use .post it sends it as POST, ($.post uses .ajax itself!!) .. thnx

Answer (score 7):

**Add below piece of code in your code before success **

```
beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")}
```

Comment: after that in my $_POST appeared my data!

Answer (score 4):

Why not call [`jQuery.post()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) directly?

```
$.post("save.php",
  $("#myform").serialize(),
  function(html) { 
    $("#mydiv").append(html);        
  },
  "html"
);
```

In regards to [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options), changing to `type: "POST"` instead of `method: "POST"` will cause a proper `POST` request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.mhtml",
        data: $("#myform").serialize(),
        success: function(html){ 
                $('#mydiv').html(html);
        }
});
```

This shows up in the Apache logs as:

```
::1 - - - [30/Oct/2009:09:44:42 -0700] "POST /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 9 "http://localhost:10501/test.mhtml" "(sic)"
```

**Possible alternate issue:**
I found [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission) while looking around at your problem.  Maybe it isn't the jQuery which is giving you trouble, it is PHP?  The top voted answer has some suggestions for ensuring that PHP isn't interfering, and the second highest answer offers some code to see if the request is actually a `POST` or not:

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo 'POSTed';
  }
?>
```

Comment: how about beforesend, complete, success ?? with .post ??

Comment: just use:
$.post("save.php", $("#myform").serialize(),function(data){$('.msg').html(data););
(3rd arugment is a function callback.)

Comment: I edited to include the third and fourth arguments.  The third argument is the callback function for when information comes back, and the fourth argument is the type of data coming back.  jQuery will do some parsing for you, if you change to JSON return type.

Comment: @Jack thanks for your example. I can see the .post works. But if you help me debug .ajax as well that would be great!!

Comment: Mostly just giving you what Sbm007 said above. They are correct, as this generates a POST request.

Answer (score 4):

I was having trouble with the variables getting lost in the mix as well and discovered that while using Rewrite Conditions to externally redirect `dir/foo.php` to `dir/foo` Apache was dropping the POST request altogether and redirecting.

So when writing the JavasSript you must reference the file in a way that it can bypass any external redirecting.

eg. Drop the extension name inline with the JavaScript.

Write

`url: "dir/foo"`

instead of

`url: "dir/foo.php"`

I hope that this helps others who found this page like me.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment helped me! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing similar problems with `$(form).ajaxSubmit()`.

Browser tools were indicating that I was successfully issuing a `POST`. On the server `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` was also indicating a `POST`, and yet the `$_POST` variable in PHP was being returned as `array(0) { }`. The problem for me was that I was actually submitting an empty form. As soon as there was data in the form, `$_POST` had something in it (as you might expect!) but more importantly, `if ($_POST) { ... }` started returning `true`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was adding the missing `.serialize()` in the `data` line of the Ajax statement:

```
data: $("#form").serialize()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing the contentType, i.e: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you have `application/json` for example, you can get the behaviour you witnessed.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    data: { 'test': jsonStr },
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    }
});
```