# POST array empty on jQuery AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, post

I hesitate to ask, as there are numerous other posts on this topic ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650516/jquery-ajax-method-post-but-post-empty) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271043/jquery-post-empty-array) for example), but none of the solutions in those posts seem to apply to me.

I am trying to pass a JSON-encoded object from a page to a PHP controller, and then respond back with some information.

If I watch in Firebug, I can see the object being sent under the 'Post' tab, however when I print out the $_GET, $_POST, and $_REQUEST arrays I see nothing at all regarding the json object.  The $_GET array at least shows my querystring of 'update-player', however POST is empty and REQUEST only shows some local cookies I have.

Here is my jQuery code.  As you can see I'm hardcoding the JSON at the moment, and the intention is that I will have a jQuery method updating the local object.

```
function sendPlayerUpdate(row, col) {
    var playerinfo = [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "row": row,
          "col": col
        }
      ];

        alert(playerinfo[0].id); //debugging

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"controller.php?a=update-player",
        //data: $.toJSON(playerinfo[0],
        data: { json: JSON.stringify(playerinfo) },
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (){

        },
        dataType: 'json'
      });
 };
```

My corresponding PHP code handling the request:

```
// update player information from AJAX POST
case "update-player":
  if (isset($_POST['json'])) echo "json received\n\n";
  else echo "json not received\n\n";
  echo "GET VARIABLES\n";
  print_r($_GET);
  echo "\n\nPOST VARIABLES\n";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo "\n\nREQUEST VARIABLES\n";
  print_r($_REQUEST);
```

And, what I see in Firebug:

[image: Firebug output]
    json not received

```
GET VARIABLES
Array
(
    [a] => update-player
)


POST VARIABLES
Array
(
)


REQUEST VARIABLES
Array
(
    [a] => update-player
    (local cookies)
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try in PHP as below (When request is an application/json, then you will not get data into $_POST)

```
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));
```

Comment: due to application/json, your json passing in body request

Comment: ahhh, makes sense...so i can just pull that into a local object and work from there.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
May be it will work for you

```
 $.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url:"controller.php?a=update-player",
data: data_json=JSON.stringify(playerinfo),
success: function (data){
},
});
```

Comment: Tried that, however the $_POST array is still empty.

Comment: can you please again post the PHP code and have you used $_POST['data_json']?

Comment: See accepted answer...I'm just going to read from the raw input data.  Thanks though!