# Send Params With Axios - VueJS

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

so I'm working with Axios in VueJS to send ajax requests. However I'm getting a bit of a problem when trying to send requests.

This is my JS code:

```
axios.post('http://localhost/app/php/search.php', {
    query: this.search //this should send the 'query' param
}).then(response => {
    this.variable = response.data
}).catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
})
```

And this is the `search.php`file:

```
<?php

    require '../Functions.php';
    $obj = new Functions();

    $array = $obj->search($_POST['query']);

    echo json_encode(array_values($array));
?>
```

And I'm getting the following error on the PHP side: `Notice:  Undefined index: query in /path/to/app/search.php on line 6`

Any reason as to why this is happening? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

`this.search` is a variable I have inside my `data` object:

```
data () {
    return {
      search: ''
    }
  }
```

This variable is binded to a textfield:

```
<input type="text" v-model="search" @keyup.enter="search()" />
```

And this inside my `search()` method is my axios request.

Comment: Not sure about axios/vuejs, but see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000386/post-array-empty-on-jquery-ajax-call . Maybe it's something similar. Same kind of thing with angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined

Comment: Where is the post performed and what is `this.search` when it is?

Comment: I updated the post @Bert.

Comment: Well, it looks like you will send an object that looks like this `{query: "whatever search is"}` to search.php. So it seems right from the client side?

Comment: Yeah, i got it working now. Thanks anyway @Bert! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I was looking at a similar problem in Angular and it turns out Axios was sending the `query` param. However, in the php file I had to populate the POST variable with the JSON coming in from Axios. This is how I got it working:

```
<?php

    require '../Functions.php';
    $obj = new Functions();

    //Populate POST variable with incoming JSON from Axios.
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST)):
        $_POST = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    endif;

    $array = $obj->search($_POST['query']);

    echo json_encode(array_values($array));
?>
```