# method="post" enctype="text/plain" are not compatible?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

When I use

```
<form method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="proc.php">
```

form data can not be sent to proc.php file properly. Why? What is the problem? Why I can't use text/plain encoding with post but I can use it with get method?

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't need to define enctype, unless you are doing a file upload, then it should be:
enctype="multipart/form-data"

[link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype)

Comment: According to w3schools ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)), `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is default.

Comment: My question is why method=“post” and enctype=“text/plain” don't work together? My HTML code does not metter and what I should use does not matter too!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What does "can not be sent to proc.php file properly" mean exactly? What does the resulting http post look like?

Comment: My html code was not figured in the text of the question, sorry. I have corrected.

Comment: @Narek I am assuming the browser doesn't know what to do with it since it isn't a valid token. I bet the browser treats enctype="text/plain" the same as enctype="cheeseburger", it does nothing....

Comment: What's the use case for wanting to do this? What information would you expect the browser to put into the content of content type text/plain?

Comment: @Alohci What is the use to use text/plain with get method?

Comment: Actually, with `method="post" enctype="text/plain"`, browser sends the data, and PHP stores it in `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, but it doesn't populate `$_POST`. Anyway, why you insist on having `text/plain`?

Comment: @Narek - Get messages shouldn't have a content body at all. [The HTTP 1.1 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics/?include_text=1) section 7.3 says "Bodies on GET requests have no defined semantics.  Note that sending a body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request."

Comment: I have no idea why the question was closed. It's a good question which already has a very good answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**[Revised]**

The answer is, because PHP doesn't handle it (and it is not a bug):

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33741

```
Valid values for enctype in <form> tag are:

application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
```

The first is the default, the second one you need only when you upload files.

**@Alohci** provided explanation why PHP doesn't populate `$_POST` array, but store the value inside a variable `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`.

Example of what can go wrong with `text/plain` enctype:

file1.php:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="file2.php">
<textarea name="input1">abc
input2=def</textarea>
<input name="input2" value="ghi" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

file2.php:

```php
<?php
print($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

Result:

```
input1=abc
input2=def
input2=ghi
```

No way to distinguish what is the value of `input1` and `input2` variables. It can be

- input1=`abc\r\ninput2=def`, input2=`ghi`, as well as
- input1=`abc`, input2=`def\r\ninput2=ghi`

No such problem when using the other two encodings mentioned before.

The difference between GET and POST:

- in GET, the variables are part of URL and are present in URL as query string, therefore they **must** be URL-encoded (and they are, even if you write `enctype="text/plain"` - it just gets ignored by the browser; you can test it using Wireshark to sniff the request packets),
- when sending POST, the variables are not part of URL, but are sent as the last header in HTTP request (POSTDATA), and you can choose whether you want to send them as `text/plain` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but the second one is the only non-ambiguous solution.

Comment: According to [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-enctype) `text/plain` is a third valid content-type for enctype. The format is described at http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#plain-text-form-data.

Comment: a nice table is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) (I already posted it)

Comment: Frankly, I never believe a word w3schools says.

Comment: Okay, this one looks more credible http://pseudo-flaw.net/content/web-browsers/form-data-encoding-roundup/ ;)

Comment: [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) is DEPRECATED in PHP 5.6, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.

Answer (score 12):

HTML5 does define how to format form data submitted as `text/plain` here: https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#plain-text-form-data.

At the bottom of that section, it says:

> Payloads using the text/plain format are intended to be human
>   readable. They are not reliably interpretable by computer, as the
>   format is ambiguous (for example, there is no way to distinguish a
>   literal newline in a value from the newline at the end of the value).

So it not unreasonable that PHP does not attempt to interpret it and only makes it available in raw form. To me, that seems the correct approach.

Comment: Broken link - you probably want https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#plain-text-form-data

Comment: @TomAnderson - Thanks. Updated link to latest W3C draft standard, but yes the WHATWG one you provide is equivalent.

Comment: I don't see the ambiguity if the form does not require newlines.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using `enctype="text/plain"` for debugging purposes, keep in mind that `$_POST` only contains associate array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the HTTP `Content-Type/enctype` in the request. So you won't be able to see anything in the script if you're printing `$_POST`in the php script.

Also there was a global variable called `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` which is DEPRECATED in PHP 5.6, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0. which you could have used to see raw form data as noted by [N'Bayramberdiyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8256347/nbayramberdiyev)