# $_POST method not working although $_Get work Fine

Tags: php

```
<?php
//    include_once '../include/user_functions.php';
    if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
        $data=$_POST['frm'];
//        user_login($data);
        var_dump($_POST['frm']);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mosaddek">
    <meta name="keyword" content="FlatLab, Dashboard, Bootstrap, Admin, Template, Theme, Responsive, Fluid, Retina">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.html">
    <title>FlatLab - Flat & Responsive Bootstrap Admin Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

  <body class="login-body">

    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" action="" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">login now</h2>
        <div class="login-wrap">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="frm[username]"autofocus>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="frm[password]" placeholder="password">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">remember me
                <span class="pull-right"> <a href="#"> forget password?</a></span>
            </label>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" value="btn-button" name="btn" >login</button>

        </div>

      </form>

    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

1. When i change form method to get that works fine.
2. when i use browser network tab headers form data has value
   [image]
3. When I change  `if(isset($_POST['btn']))` to `vardump($_POST)` it return `array(0) { }` all the time.
4. I run php on xampp

> upload_max_filesize=130M
>   post_max_size=130M

any additional information needed?

Comment: @Martin i changed that to input type="sumbit". it doesnt work for me

Comment: `<input type='submit'>` is what you want (you got a typo in your comment)

Comment: Also try `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { print "posted ok"; }`

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111496/php-post-is-empty?noredirect=1&lq=1) help you?

Comment: @Martin that code reutrn posted ok

Comment: @Martin doesnt help . i didnt change default form enctype

Comment: @Martin `<button type="submit">` is perfectly valid HTML, easier to work with and [has less quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable).

Comment: @DouwedeHaan yes  I  suspected that button was valid

Comment: MovAhed ok, so the POST data is posted; but your  detection of this is at fault. THerefore write: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { var_dump($_POST); }` and see what data your form actually sends `:-)`

Comment: @Martin array(0) { }

Comment: Go to the Network tab of the browser's console, do you see it sending the parameters when you submit the form?

Comment: Can you turn off your CSP- specifically "upgrade insecure requests" and try again?

Comment: Had a similar issue with making a HTTP POST via Angular it was coming thru with an empty $_POST array but I could read the data with `file_get_contents("php://input")` and then parse it from there...

Comment: @ivanivan it works for me too. it can be solved to vardump array?

Comment: maybe... can you do `$res=file_get_contents("php://input");print($res);` and post the results?

Comment: @ivanivan yeah .

Answer (score 1):

I *think* your issue is your use of the [**Content Security Policy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) Header ["*Upgrade Insecure Requests*"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests) which has a couple of [minor bugs](https://github.com/twitter/secure_headers/issues/348) when used over plain (insecure) HTTP.

Because your `localhost` is HTTP this might be interrupting the POST data because the "Upgrade Insecure Requests" header is trying to send to a HTTPS address and so *might* be blocking (stripping) out the POST data when finding it can't reach  .

Please try and disable your "upgrade insecure requests" header (and possibly clear your browser cache) and see if this helps your issue?

It may also depend on the browser used, as [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) is only currently on some browsers.