# php - email form

Tags: php, forms, email

rough day and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but could someone glance over this and explain why I'm getting a blank email?  I've broken this down as much as possible but can't seem to find the reason why its blank

```
<?php
$to = 'blah@blah.com';
$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$subject = "Message from: $name";
$message = $_POST['comment'] ;
$robotest = $_REQUEST['robotest'];
$body = "From: $name \r\nMessage: $message";

/*
if (preg_match($match, $from) ||
preg_match($match, $subject) ||
preg_match($match, $body)) {
die("Header injection detected.");
}
*/

if ($sent == '0') {
mail($to, $subject, $body) or die("Error Bro!!!");
$sent = 1;
}

if ($robotest) {
$error = print("You are a gutless robot.");
}

 if ($name == ' '){
print("You have not entered a name, please go back and try again");
 } else {
$send = mail($to, $subject, $body);
print("Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.");
 }
 ?>
```

html:

```
            <form style="margin-left: 10%;" method="post" action="coming-soon/email.php" enctype="text/plain">
                <br>
                <input id="fName" name="name" type="text"  placeholder="Name (required)"><br><br>
                <p class="robotic" id="pot">
                    <label>If you're human leave this blank:</label>
                    <input name="robotest" type="text" id="robotest" class="robotest" />
                </p>
                <textarea id="fComment" name="comment" style="height: inherit; margin: 0 40% 1% 0;" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Place your Message here...."></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
            </form>
```

Comment: What type of server is this on? some boxes don't have sendmail capabilities, or require you to make some changes to the http.conf file (like an email server, admin email address etc.)

Also, did you check your junkmail folder?

Comment: At quick glance everything looks ok.  Are you sure those variables actually have something stored in them?

Comment: What's the point of the `if($sent == '0')`?

Comment: @Syndrose the email is sending, but the fields are returning blank in the email.

Comment: @350_Design The variables are supposed to be pulling from the html page and I'm typing in them but it seems to not be pulling from the fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove and it should work.  Have a look here as well [method="post" enctype="text/plain" are not compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible)

```
 enctype="text/plain"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got me headed down the right track....those variables are definitely weird

Comment: Found the problem seems you cannot use text/plain.

Comment: wow...I was looking at that text/plain so many times.  Thanks so much