# cannot get the POST variables from email form

Tags: php, forms, email, variables, post

I cant get the POST variables from this email form.

Any suggestions?

the part of the form in html file:

```
<form id="form_28" name="register" onsubmit="return validate_form_28(this)" action="sendmail.php" method="post" target="_blank" enctype="text/plain" style="margin:0;position:absolute;left:67px;top:297px;width:576px;height:291px;">
<input type="text" id="edit_23" name="email" value="" style="position:absolute; left:290px; top:93px; width:209px;">
</form>
```

the sendmail.php file

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'] ;


$email_body =  "Here is the message";
mail( "mymail@mysite.com", "title", $email_body, "From: $email" );
print "Congratulations your email has been sent";

?>
```

the validate_form_28 :

```
function validate_form_28( form )
{
    if( ltrim(rtrim(form.elements['email'].value,' '),' ')=="" ) { alert("you have to fill it"); form.elements['email'].focus(); return false; }
    if(!ValidateEmail(form.elements['email'].value)) { alert("not valid emailv"); form.elements['email'].focus(); return false; }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you close the form tag somewhere ?

Comment: So... What is the error? `$email` is not being used btw

Comment: Are you getting any errors? what happens when you do `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: @k102 `$email` is used in the From

Comment: can we see the "return validate_form_28(this)" ? maybe validate_form_28(this) is returning false or screwing the script up

Comment: function validate_form_28( form )
{
    if( ltrim(rtrim(form.elements['email'].value,' '),' ')=="" ) { alert("you have to fill this"); form.elements['email'].focus(); return false; }
    if(!ValidateEmail(form.elements['email'].value)) { alert("not email form"); form.elements['email'].focus(); return false; }
    return true;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello please remove the **enctype="text/plain"**

**text/plain** = Spaces are converted to "+" symbols, but no special characters are encoded

Answer (score 3):

close your form.

`</form>`

And change:

```
mail( "mymail@mysite.com", "title", $email_body, "From: $email" );
```

to

```
mail( "mymail@mysite.com", "title", $email_body, "From: " . $email );
```

Comment: FYI: `"From: $email"` and `"From: " . $email` do the exact same thing.

Comment: True. But it's still makes no difference in the code and how it functions.

Comment: Don't use `"` in php unless you need the contents to be parsed, otherwise use `'` (this way the PHP engine doesn't waste time looking at it).

Comment: it would save 0.000000001 seconds or so not using the double quote xD even in a big application it wouldn't really be noticeable, I would say to be careful for injections sometimes, and use whatever is more comfortable, the time saved for a human writting/reading IS noticeable

Answer (score 0):

I played around a bit and php and `enctype="text/plain"` is not compatible, take it out and it should work:

[reference from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible)