# Emails from Form coming in empty?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Wondering if anyone out there could help me spot the flaw in my form setup? Emails are coming through, but with none of the information entered by the message sender:

> Email Body:
>
> Name:
>
> Email:
>
> Existing Customer:
>
> Org Type:
>
> Message:

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="email.php" method="POST" name="contact" enctype="text/plain">

            <label for="name">Name: </label><input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            <label for="email">Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br><br>

            <label for="existing">Have you written before?</label>
            <input type="radio" name="existing" value="Yes" id="existingyes">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="existing" value="No" id="existingno">No<br><br>

            <label for="orgtype">How do you classify yourself? </label><select id="orgtype">
                <option>Charity</option>
                <option>Business</option>
                <option>Individual</option>
                <option>Meat Popcicle</option>
                <option>Other</option>
            </select><br><br>

            <label for="essay">Thoughts? Questions? Comments</label><br>
            <textarea name="essay" rows="3" cols="70" id="essay">...</textarea><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Yell At Us!"><br>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
    <?php
  $name    = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
  $email   = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
  $existing   = stripslashes($_POST['existing']);
  $orgtype = stripslashes($_POST['orgtype']);
  $essay = stripslashes($_POST['essay']);
  $form_message = "Name: $name \nEmail: $email \nExisting Customer: $existing \nOrg Type: $orgtype \nMessage: $essay";
  $success = mail("myemail@email.com", "Online Form Submission", $form_message, "From: $email" );
  if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";

    } else {

echo "Sorry error please try again..."; 

}

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `enctype="text/plain"` from you're `form` tag.

`<form action="email.php" method="POST" name="contact">`

You can read about it here
[method="post" enctype="text/plain" are not compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible)