# Having an issue with PHP $_POST

Tags: php, html

I am trying to tie my html form to a PHP mailer and for some reason the form inputs are not storing in my variables. I have tried searching all over and I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Form handler:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $date = trim($_POST["date"]);
    $guests = trim($_POST["guests"]);
    $description = trim($_POST["description"]);
}
```

Form:

```
<form role="form" class="text-center" method="POST" enctype="text/plain" action="index.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Correo Electrónico</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Fecha del Evento</label>
      <input type="date" id="date" class="form-control" name="date">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="guests">Número de Huéspedes</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="guests" name="guests">
        <option>1 - 2</option>
        <option>3 - 4</option>
        <option>5 - 6</option>
        <option>7 - 8</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description">Descripción de Evento</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="3" name="description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;">
      <label for="address">Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

For PHP `text/plain` is not a valid value for `enctype` in `<form>`

[Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible)

Comment: It is, just not for PHP.

Comment: I've never ever seen an `enctype` other than `"multipart/form-data"`. Is anything else valid in a form?

Comment: @Rudie I believe the default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but this format is not good to upload files. At least not to PHP. Thats why, when uploading files, the enctype `multipart/form-data` is specified.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, you are right... I was to fast hitting post :P

Comment: I changed the `enctype` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but it still doesn't seem to be taking any of the data.