# unable to create a php file using php

Tags: php

What i am trying to do is, is try to write a file with the user inputted details relating to database connection. But i am unable to do so. The file is not being created.

My php code:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['config'] == 'save_config')
{
$string = '<?php
           $mysql_database = "'.$_POST["databasename"].'";
           $mysql_user = "'.$_POST["username"].'";   
           $mysql_password = "'.$_POST["password"].'";            
           $mysql_host = "'.$_POST["host"].'";
           $db = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
           if (!$db)
           {
           die("Failed to connect to database server!<br>".mysql_error());
           }
           mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db) or die("Failed to select database<br>".mysql_error());
           ?>';

$file="./config.php";
if(!file_exists($file)){
    if(!($handle=fopen($file, "w"))){
        die("Cannot create the file!");
    }
    else{
        fwrite($handle, $string);
        fclose($handle);
    }
    }
}
?>
```

My HTML code:

```
<form name="setup" method="post" action="index.php" enctype="text/plain" id="Form1">
<input type="hidden" name="config" value="save_config">
<input type="submit" id="Submit" name="" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:14px;top:270px;width:75px;height:31px;z-index:4;">
<input type="text" id="databasename" style="position:absolute;left:181px;top:21px;width:223px;height:22px;line-height:22px;z-index:5;" name="databasename" value="" required="required">
<input type="text" id="username" style="position:absolute;left:181px;top:81px;width:223px;height:22px;line-height:22px;z-index:10;" name="username" value="" required="required">
<input type="password" id="password" style="position:absolute;left:181px;top:145px;width:223px;height:22px;line-height:22px;z-index:11;" name="password" value="" required="required">
<input type="text" id="host" style="position:absolute;left:181px;top:211px;width:223px;height:22px;line-height:22px;z-index:12;" name="host" value="" required="required" placeholder="localhost">
</form>
```

Comment: Any errors? Do you have write permissions?

Comment: @putvande, am running it on wamp.

Comment: @putvande, its giving undefined index: config on line 2

Comment: The error is unrelated to the question title.

Comment: Yeah I know, but am not worried about the error.  I am asking why the file is not being created

Comment: Because an error stops the execution of the script. You need to fix this error first.

Comment: No its not what I am looking for.

Comment: @JakeGould, its not at all a duplicate to the question you reffered. Instead it might be of some help to others who are looking for setting up some kind of installation system. Do correct me if am wrong. P.s no hard feelings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php, wherever you have the three letters of `<?php` or the two letters `?>` next to each other it will mean "start/end php code here" even if it's in a middle of a `''` quote pair. Just separate them with a concatenation like this:

```
$string = '<'.'?php
    ....
    ?'.'>';
```

You could also use the [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax too here, that can work without separating the tokens:

```
$string = <<<EOD
<?php
....
?>
EOD;
```

Also, in php you can leave out the ending `?>`. The file end will work just fine to tell the interpreter that it's end of a php block.

Comment: Okay, tried it just now bt its still not working. Giving undefined index config on line 2

Comment: That just means that whatever called your script doesn't POST-ed a `config` parameter to it. From your HTML part it looks to me that you have an `enctype` that php doesn't understand. Just remove the `ecntype="..."` from the `<form>` tag, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible