# Php reading from HTML checkbox and choose appropriate query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have an HTML file with a check box as follows:

```
 <body>
<div id="wb_Web_Reports" style="position:absolute;left:329px;top:143px;width:510px;height:244px;z-index:4;">
<form name="Web_Reports" method="post" action="stsarrival.php" enctype="text/plain" id="Web_Reports">
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:210px;top:184px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:0;">
<input type="text" id="ArrivalDate" style="position:absolute;left:140px;top:71px;width:253px;height:33px;line-height:33px;z-index:1;" name="ArrivalDate" value="">
<div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:195px;top:34px;width:234px;height:16px;z-index:2;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">From Arrival Date:</span></div>
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" name="Checkbox1" value="on" style="position:absolute;left:442px;top:71px;z-index:3;" onclick="document.getElementById('ArrivalDate').disabled=this.checked;">
   </form>
```

The php file to which this is posting (stsarrival.php) should run a query if the check box is selected and run a different query if the check box is not selected. I wrote the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['[Checkbox1]'])) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM Main_Data_Table INNER JOIN Title ON 
Main_Data_Table.TitleID = Title.ID INNER JOIN Agent ON Main_Data_Table.AgentID = Agent.ID 
INNER JOIN Accommodation ON Main_Data_Table.AccommodationID = Accommodation.ID 
INNER JOIN `Host Family details` ON Main_Data_Table.HostFamilyID = `Host Family details`.ID 
INNER JOIN Transfers ON Main_Data_Table.TransferId = Transfers.ID 
INNER JOIN `Board Basis` ON Main_Data_Table.BoardBasisID = `Board Basis`.ID 
INNER JOIN `Course Booked` ON Main_Data_Table.CourseTypeID = `Course Booked`.ID");
} else {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM Main_Data_Table INNER JOIN Title ON 
Main_Data_Table.TitleID = Title.ID INNER JOIN Agent ON Main_Data_Table.AgentID = Agent.ID 
INNER JOIN Accommodation ON Main_Data_Table.AccommodationID = Accommodation.ID 
INNER JOIN `Host Family details` ON Main_Data_Table.HostFamilyID = `Host Family details`.ID 
INNER JOIN Transfers ON Main_Data_Table.TransferId = Transfers.ID 
INNER JOIN `Board Basis` ON Main_Data_Table.BoardBasisID = `Board Basis`.ID 
INNER JOIN `Course Booked` ON Main_Data_Table.CourseTypeID = `Course Booked`.ID 
  WHERE (Main_Data_Table.`Arrival Date` = '2014-09-01')");
}
```

However I am always getting the result of one query regardless of whether the check box is selected or not.

Please help...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the solution was very very simple - I am ashamed to say...

I was writing

```
['[Checkbox1]']
```

instead of

```
 ['Checkbox1']
```

so the full working line is:

```
if (isset($_POST['Checkbox1'])&& $_POST['Checkbox1'] == 1)
```

there were two extra [ ]...

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

`isset` returns a boolean, so it will never equal the string `"on"`. Simply remove that:

```
if (isset($_POST['Checkbox1'])) {
```

There is no need to check the value, as the key will not exist in the post array if the checkbox is not selected

Comment: Then something else is wrong, as this code is as simple as can be. What does `var_dump($_POST);` look like?

Comment: it returns array(0) { }

Comment: @elstiv OK then none of your form data is being posted. Please edit your question to show the complete form

Comment: @elstiv you need to remove `enctype="text/plain"` from your form tag, then everything should work

Comment: For an explanation why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible

Comment: my var_dump is now showing: array(2) { ["ArrivalDate"]=> string(0) "" ["Checkbox1"]=> string(1) "1" }

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
$query  = "
SELECT *  
  FROM Main_Data_Table m
  JOIN Title ti
    ON m.TitleID = ti.ID 
  JOIN Agent ag
    ON m.AgentID = ag.ID 
  JOIN Accommodation ac
    ON m.AccommodationID = ac.ID 
  JOIN `Host Family details` d
    ON m.HostFamilyID = d.ID 
  JOIN Transfers tr
    ON m.TransferId = tr.ID 
  JOIN `Board Basis` b
    ON m.BoardBasisID = b.ID 
  JOIN `Course Booked` c
    ON m.CourseTypeID = c.ID
";


if (isset($_POST['Checkbox1'])&& $_POST['Checkbox1'] == 1){
$query .=  " WHERE m.`Arrival Date` = '2014-09-01'";
}
```

... but don't use "SELECT *" and don't use spaces in column/table names. IT WILL DRIVE YOU BONKERS

Answer (score 0):

Change code from:

```
if (isset($_POST['Checkbox1'])== "on") {
```

To:

```
if (isset($_POST['Checkbox1']) && $_POST['Checkbox1'] == "on") {
```

Also try not to use the `mysql_*` functions, as they are deprecated!

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also the MySQL API Overview for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['Checkbox1']) && $_POST['Checkbox1'] == "on") 
{
}
else 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not give the value of the check box as on or off. Just give a one or zero. Try to submit your form and check for what value comes in through the post. Based on the value you can write the conditions you want.