# PHP Inserting empty record in MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert records in a MySQL DB, but I'm getting no values from the POST variable.

I can see a new record is being entered with a record ID, but 0 in the next and only cell in the table.
The cell type is a **Double** in form.html.

*I've hidden the submit button for design purposes. This is developed for a mobile experience.*

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","DB");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$cal = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cali']);
$sql="INSERT INTO `calibration` (`Calibration`) VALUES ('$cal')";
echo $sql;
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Calibration Complete!";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**form.html**

```
<form enctype="text/plain" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="cali" value="Please calibration value" onclick='javascript: this.value = ""' >
<input type="submit" style="margin-left: -1000px;">
</form>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The onclick is setting the value to "".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed the onlick function, and I'm getting the same result of no value in the cell.

Comment: Another thing besides Björn's comment, remove this `enctype="text/plain"` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Lovely! That worked! I kept the onclick and it's working. Do you mind posting it as an answer. :)

Comment: It has been done, as per your request. @ahmadux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP's request.

Another thing besides Björn's comment <= (giving credit to).

> *The onclick is setting the value to `""`*

Remove this `enctype="text/plain"` and you should be good to go.

A more detailed explanation about the use of `enctype="text/plain"` can be found on Stack, with the following answer given:

- **https://stackoverflow.com/a/7628491/**

including a link to **https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33741**

with the following at the end of that page:

> Sorry, but your problem does not imply a bug in PHP itself.  For a
>   list of more appropriate places to ask for help using PHP, please
>   visit http://www.php.net/support.php as this bug system is not the
>   appropriate forum for asking support questions.  Due to the volume
>   of reports we can not explain in detail here why your report is not
>   a bug.  The support channels will be able to provide an explanation
>   for you.
>
> Thank you for your interest in PHP.
>   Valid values for enctype in  tag are:
>
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - multipart/form-data