# 404 error, on mamp server, file not found

Tags: php, html, forms, http-status-code-404, mamp

I get the following 404 error when trying to access a PHP file on MAMP

"The requested URL /‘welcome.php’ was not found on this server."

Both the html file and the php file run fine via localhost just not from the file action.

They are in the same location and the action looks like action='welcome.php'

```
  <html><head charset=“utf-8”>></head><form action=‘welcome.php’ enctype="text/plain" method=“post”>      

  First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name: <input type="text"   

  name="lastname"> <button action=“submit”>Submit </button> </form> </html>
```

welcome.php looks like this

```
  <html> <body> Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br> Your email address is: <?php echo   

   $_POST["email"]; ?> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Don't use MSWORD when coding. Use a code editor. Your curly quotes `“ ”` and `‘ ’` are what's causing this.

Comment: at bellow my answer is right .. what the reason of down vote @Yoni Tareke

Answer (score 2):

You have a few curly quotes in your code `“ ”` and `‘ ’` which will explain the "file not found" error for your form's action `action=‘welcome.php’`. You should also remove `enctype="text/plain"` - [**consult this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7628491/) on Stack for more information about it.

You are also using the wrong names `name="firstname"` and `$_POST["name"]`.
Also `name="lastname"` and `$_POST["email"]`, those must match.

Your Html file should now read as:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and welcome.php file:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did `not` downvote, but I can tell by your [original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25894145/1) that you had not changed the `“ ”` and `‘ ’` in OP's code. Most probable reason and that person has not retracted it.

Comment: But Sir @Fred i am give the full answer ..with solve the error .. is it sir

Comment: It was me. @Fred-ii- was right, when the original answer was published, it has illegal quotes still present, so I've downvoted it. Now I've pulled my vote back.

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan I made a few modifications/clarifications to your answer in order to point out to the OP, where the errors were made. It's always best to do that and to give a detailed answer. ;)

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan You're welcome. Sorry, I do not give out my Email publicly. See my Website ;)

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan Why do you want me to have your Email address?

Comment: @Fred-ii- your are more senior and i see your profile too really awesome .i need some guide-line from you if you don't have any problem and this is my ferrakkem@gmail.com ... thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

> The requested URL /**‘welcome.php’** was not found on this server.

This is because you use wrong quotes (quotation marks) in your HTML. In markup you should use nothing else then `"` or `'`.

So your code should looks like:

```
<html>
<head charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>
  <form action="welcome.php" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <button action="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This `enctype="text/plain"` should be removed. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7628491/ for more information about that.

Comment: Using `enctype="text/plain"` will fail, just thought you would like to know that.

Comment: I did not refactor the original code (except `body` tag). Just managed the quotes and format. And also you are almost right (atleast for that `welcome.php`). However, even if you submit the form with `enctype="text/plain"` you can still catch the data in PHP with `file_get_contents('php://input')`.