# Getting emailed results

Tags: php, forms

I've created a HTML form and used PHP to get the results emailed to me but Im having problems...

I have a PHP file called contact.php and the code is

```
<?php
      $email = $_POST['emails'] ;
      $password = $_POST['pass'] ;
      mail("MYEMAIL", "Form Results", "You have received a new message. Email: $email Password: $password");
?>
```

And my HTML is

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
   <div class="size">Email</div> <input type="text" name="emails"><br>
   <div class="size">Password</div><input type="password" name="pass">
   <div class="logincon"><input type="image" src="css/images/login.png" value="submit" /></div>    
   <br><br>
</form>
```

When I fill out the form, I get a email saying
You have received a new message. Email: Password:
The email and password isn't being displayed.

Comment: Is the php and html in the same file - `contact.php`?

Comment: Always check if your POST values are set and not empty.

Comment: @Sean The fact that the email is being sent just without the variables would suggest it is

Comment: If they are the same file, check if the form is posted first -> `if(isset($_POST['emails'])){ $email = $_POST['emails'] ; $password = $_POST['pass'] ; mail(...your code...);}`. This prevents an email being sent on initial page load.

Comment: @Sean very good suggestion - that could very well be the case.

Comment: Doesn't $_POST require enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?

Answer (score 2):

The php `$_POST` requires `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Change this in your html

```
<form action="contact.php"
method="post"
enctype="text/plain">
```

to

```
<form action="contact.php"
method="post"
enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

and it should work.

You can read more on the subject here:
[method="post" enctype="text/plain" are not compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible)

> Payloads using the text/plain format are intended to be human readable. They are not reliably interpretable by computer, as the format is ambiguous (for example, there is no way to distinguish a literal newline in a value from the newline at the end of the value).

However you could access the data from a text/plain post with: `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, but you have to parse it yourself.

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default and does not need to be explicitly stated. You only need to use `enctype=` when using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` -> http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype.

Comment: Yes it is default, but OP has specified `'text/plain'` which makes his `$_POST` empty.

Comment: @caeth Ah! Excellent! Nice catch there

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mail("MYEMAIL", "Form Results", "You have received a new message. Email: " . $email . " Password: " . $password);
```

Comment: This really shouldn't be the issues as the double quoted string allows variable substitution

Comment: I thought that as well, no harm in giving it a try. Also would expect "$email" in the actual email as well.