# PHP/Wordpress - Trying to mail an order form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a rather large form built, and unfortunately my friend is using WordPress. After much research of how to get PHP to run on an individual page, I created a custom template for the page and inserted my PHP which is to read that it was a post, and send a wp_email accordingly.

My form starts out:

```
 <form name="healthyOrderForm" method="POST" action="/order-sent"  enctype="text/plain">
```

the /order-sent does send it to the correct page as I can see my php response when it gets there.
Form submit button is:

```
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit Order" />
```

PHP is:

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = 'testemail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'New Healthy Order';
    $message .= 'Location: ' . $_POST['location'] ;
    $headers = "From: randomemail@gmail.com\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    $success = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for over 24 hours now.

Comment: Why is it unfortunate that your friend is using Wordpress? And what exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: The problem is that the email is not sent would be the problem (I just like building from scratch, less restrictions)

Comment: Using error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would signal a few things. Something you're not doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no `$_POST['submit']`. The name of your submit is `$_POST["send"]`. Check on that.

EDIT

And, as Fred-ii- pointed me to that, remove the `enctype="text/plain"` from your `form` tag.

Comment: Not just that, but OP  needs to remove `enctype="text/plain"`

Comment: @user1231771 You're welcome. Happy to have been of help, *cheers*

Comment: More information can be read at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7628491/ @user1231771 as to why the enctype failed.