# PHP input fields not being received. Spent 2 days - can't solve

Tags: php, forms

I'm thinking this is an easy fix for someone who's familiar with PHP. I've been searching for an answer for 2 days. While great information, none is solving.  See the 3rd section below – I receive the form less the field info.
What am I doing wrong?

Note that the form itself is wrapped in `<html><body><section>` tags which don’t appear below.

This is the form:

```
<form name="Seller" id="restaurant-fm" action="send2.php"  method="POST" enctype="text/plain">  
<input type="text" name="name" required="required" id="name" size="25"       
 value="" placeholder="Your name" autocomplete="on" tabindex="1"          

class="txtinput">
<input type="email" name="email" required="required" id="email" size="25" value="" placeholder="Your e-mail address" autocomplete="on" tabindex="2"        
class="txtinput">       
<input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your phone number" tabindex="3" size="12" value="" class="txtinput">
<textarea name="message" id="inquiry" placeholder="(Optional) Enter message here..." tabindex="4" class="txtblock"></textarea> 

<section id="buttons">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn" class="submitbtn" tabindex="6" value="CLICK TO GET STARTED">
<br style="clear:both;">
</section>
</form>
```

2) This is the PHP send script I’m using:

```
<?PHP
$name= $_POST['name1'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$inquiry= $_POST['message'];
$to ="myname@mydomain.com";
$subject= "New Contact";
$message= "A visitor sent you the following information: \n\nname:$name; \n\nemail:$email; \n\nphone:$phone; \n\nmessage:$message; \n\nPlease respond to this inquiry immediately";
$headers = "From: $email";
{mail($to,$subject,$message);
header("Location:/About.html");}
?>
```

3) Here’s what I receive from the form:

```
A visitor sent you the following information: 

name:; 

email:; 

phone:; 

message:;
```

Comment: Where is `form`opening tag?

Comment: first get rid of `enctype="text/plain"` which is the main reason. and you have no `name1` name attribute, you have `name`. Check for errors. Consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: *Please respond to this inquiry immediately*? Rude. Debug your code by var_dump($_POST); and go from there.

Comment: and what's with the `{...}`??

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm heading over to the link now.

Comment: @MikelBitson - actually... That's from the email that's being sent.

Comment: RE the name1, I did fix that. Trying 2 days worth of little changes, caused it, but appreciate that catch as well.

Comment: I've said what was wrong with your code.

Comment: I'm going to take {...} that out now and try again.

Comment: here's another fail `$headers = "From: $email";` and error reporting would have told you about that also. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @andrewsi Ahhh, my b! *Not* rude!

Comment: Fred, I read your last comment in which you said you already answered what was wrong with my code. Glad you wrote that. I focused!. lol Anyway, that was the problem. I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: @– Fred -ii- I just want to make sure that you're aware that you solved my issue. First time post so I may be getting this @– Fred -ii- wrong, but I really appreciate that you helped. Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to remove `enctype="text/plain"` from your form tags.

Read the following Q&A on Stack about it; it's more descriptive:

- [method="post" enctype="text/plain" are not compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible)

Then you're using `<input type="text" name="name"...` and using `name` as the name attribute, yet you using `name1` for the POST array `$_POST['name1']`.

You also have a bunch of semi-colons in your `$message= "A visitor....` which are end of statement characters; remove them.

Then you have the following which isn't included in your `mail()` function, therefore the `from` never happens.

```
$headers = "From: $email";
```

and you also need to add the `$headers` variable to `mail($to,$subject,$message);`

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

- Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You also need to remove the braces from:

```
{mail($to,$subject,$message);
header("Location:/About.html");}
```

Those are mostly used in conditional statements, which you probably meant to use.

I.e.:

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
    header("Location:/About.html");
    exit;
    }

else{
    echo "Mail failed. Check your logs";
    }
```

Sidenote: It's always best to add `exit;` after a header. Otherwise and if you have more code following it, your code may want to continue to execute.

```
mail($to,$subject,$message);
    header("Location:/About.html");
    exit;
```

- Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Having used error reporting, would have signaled quite a few notices.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Final notes.

It's best to check against your inputs for emptyness.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

I.e.: `if(!empty($var)){...}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing `value=""` Also remove all semicolons after the variables in your message string e.g. change `$name;` to just `$name`

Make sure your name field is called the same as the `POST` variable you are collecting (currently name seems to be being sent but the script is looking for name1).

Can you `echo` the variables from your script as they arrive?

On most servers you will need to make the "from" a domain on your server and add a "replyto" for the email address from the form. Remember to clean up your input data to avoid script attack.

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions. [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: your edits are getting closer, but you missed something. A few actually.