# PHP not receiving data from HTML5 form

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post

I am recently getting into php and am running it locally on Xampp. I have created the following simple form followed by a few lines of php. It seems that no data is being passed through from the html form to the php page.

```
<form method="post" action="emailform.php" enctype="text/plain" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row input">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="subject">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row input">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="full name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="subject" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5 textarea">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="4" placeholder="message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the simple php code I am using to test:

```
<?php            
        $subject = 'No subject was set';
        if (isset($_POST['subject'])) {
            $subject = ($_POST['subject']);
        }
        echo "This is the subject:$subject"; 
    ?>
```

I appreciate any help as I have been struggling with this simple code for the past week now.

Comment: does all two files in same directory ?

Comment: remove enctype="text/plain" from form

Comment: Yes both files are in the same directory

Comment: two subject names! `<input type="email" name="subject" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email">` and `<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="subject">`

Comment: I have removed the enctype attribute but still the same result

Comment: It's working for me if I remove the enctype. Are you sure you're not loading the page from cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two subject names!

```
<input type="email" name="subject" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email">
                          ^
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="subject">
                         ^
```

Also remove `enctype="text/plain"` from the form

It's because PHP [doesn't handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible)