# Send email from HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'my@email.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

This is my PHP File which is I am using to send an email please check this.
The Following is the HTML Code.

I have tried on server also it gives me error that "all fields are required"
Basically, variables are not getting any data from the HTML form.

```
<form action="email.php" method="post" name="contact_form" enctype="text/plain">
  <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" style="border-radius: 0px; margin-bottom: 3%">

    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" style="border-radius: 0px; margin-bottom: 3%">

    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="message" id="message" style="border-radius: 0px; margin-bottom: 3%"></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="border-radius: 0px; background-color: midnightblue; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888; color: white;">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Most like invalid enctype? See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible

Comment: so instead of text/plain what should i use ? @AntonyThompson

Comment: Soooooooooo many questions have been made on Stackoverflow about this, did you even bother to search?

Comment: @AkshatShah The answer in the link i gave tells you :P. It's `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @AkshatShah Better yet, just remove the enctype from the form element. It will default to the correct one. The only time you really need to set it is for file uploads

Comment: Also, its better to use [`filter_var()`](https://www.google.nl/search?q=filter_var+email+in+php&oq=filter_var+email+in+php) to validate email addresses

Answer (score 0):

I have removed **enctype** from your **Form**. Also write script in same page. Try with this code (Save this script as **index.php**):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send_email'])) {
    $errors = '';
    $myemail = 'my@email.com'; //<-----Put Your email address here.
    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
        $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
    }
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email_address)) {
        $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
    }
    if (empty($errors)) {
        $to = $myemail;
        $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
        $email_body = "You have received a new message. " .
            " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message";
        $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
        if (mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers)) {
            echo 'mail sent';
        } else {
            echo 'mail not sent';
        }
    }
}
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" style="border-radius: 0px; margin-bottom: 3%">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" style="border-radius: 0px; margin-bottom: 3%">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="message" id="message" style="border-radius: 0px; margin-bottom: 3%"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="send_email" class="btn btn-default" style="border-radius: 0px; background-color: midnightblue; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888; color: white;">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I thinks your code is vulnerable to header injection.

Comment: @RazibAlMamun, yes i know i just edited Akshat code.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove in form tage enctype="text/plain"