# isset($_POST['submit']) always false

Tags: php, html

Im trying to create a contact form using php,and having some troubles.

the condition: `isset($_POST['submit'])` always produces false, even if I just submit a blank page.

here is my code:

contact.html part:

```
<form action='emailto.php' method='POST' enctype='text/plain'>
First Name:<br>
<input type='text' name='firstname'><br>
Last Name:<br>
<input type='text' name='lastname'><br>
Email Address:<br>
<input type='text' name='emailadd' ><br>
Subject:<br>
<input type='text' name='subject' ><br>
Message:<br>
<textarea name='message' rows=5 cols=30 ></textarea><br><br>
<input type='submit' value='Send' name='submit'>
</form>
```

emailto.php:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "emailaddress";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$Emailadd = $_POST['emailadd'];
$Message = $_POST['message'];
$Body= "";
$Body .= $firstname;
$Body .= $lastname;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $Emailadd;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $Message;
mail($to,$subject,$Body);
echo "Mail Sent! <a href='contact.html'>Go Back</a>";
} else {
header("Location: contact.html");
exit(0);
}
?>
```

Besides, what's weird is that if I delete the if-else statement in emailto.php,
after submitting, an error message will occur: undifined index: subject, firstname, lastname, emailadd, message...

I was totally confused.. 
Looking forward to hear some advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also be aware that `isset()` returns true for a variable defined as empty string (such as a blank POST data field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this `enctype='text/plain'` from your form and it will start working; *I guarantee it.* And if it fails, then you need to find out why that is and making sure that mail is available for you to use.

Sidenote: You should also check if any of the inputs are empty (and `required` which helps).

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

and use proper (full) headers for `mail()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Otherwise, your mailout may be treated as spam or rejected altogether.

There should be a valid `From: <email>` as part of mail's 4th argument.

I.e. and from the manual:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

> *"Besides, what's weird is that if I delete the if-else statement in emailto.php, after submitting, an error message will occur: undifined index: subject, firstname, lastname, emailadd, message..."*

- Again; this is caused by `enctype='text/plain'` in the form which isn't a valid enctype for using the POST array.

---

**Edit:**

Add an `if/else` to `mail()`. If it echos *"Houston we have a problem"*, then there's a problem on your end.

If it echo *"Mail Sent!"* but no mail is received, then look at your spam box. Mail has done its job and you need to find out why it was never sent/received.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "emailaddress";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$Emailadd = $_POST['emailadd'];
$Message = $_POST['message'];
$Body= "";
$Body .= $firstname;
$Body .= $lastname;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $Emailadd;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $Message;

if(mail($to,$subject,$Body)){
echo "Mail Sent! <a href='contact.html'>Go Back</a>";
} else { echo "Houston, we have a problem"; }

} else {
header("Location: contact.html");
exit(0);
}
?>
```

Comment: Something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible

Comment: @Progrock Yes. However, I added a few things in my answer in order to help them out. Hopefully everything will go well and as intended.

Comment: THX! Really Helpful!

Comment: @NicoleYan You may like to mark the question/answer as solved in order to inform everyone/the Stack system that a solution was found. Otherwise it will be considered as "still open/unsolved" and others may think that they should post more answers. *Welcome to Stack*