# Why is enctype text/plain not recommended?

Tags: html, forms, form-data, enctype

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype

Here I find that "text/plain" is only used for debugging, but no further information is available such as why it is only used for debugging.

When I try this with "non-file" data it is very practical. Everything is separated by a "new line" and are easy to handle.

What's the catch? E.g Are there characters that can create problems?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible

Comment: Is it just the new lines that are the problem? Can't find anything else in the link. In that case, you just need to search and replace the new lines with your own custom tag (that are not already included in the message) before you send it to the server?

Then the server, instead of searching for every single hex that can occur (and then replace them) it can just search for the replacement.

Sounds lighter and more efficient.