# Why received empty data using $_POST function in php side from the posted HTML form textfield

Tags: php, http, html-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php $_POST array empty upon form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission)

I just make a simple test to POST a HTML format's textfield data to PHP server.  And,  in PHP server side, just use the $_POST[] function to retrive the posted data. 
However, there is empty(null) data recevied always. Attached below are the HTML code and php script I tested. 
Appreaicted if you can point me where I was wrong?

----HTML code---
senddata.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="receivedata.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="form1" id="form1">
  <label>_id
  <input name="_id" type="text" id="_id" />
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>Send
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send" />
  </label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---PHP Script-----
receivedata.php

```
<?php  

echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."<BR/>" ;
$id = $_post['_id'];
if ( isset($id))
{
  echo "Data set ready!<br/>";
  echo "id=".$id."<br/>";      
}
else
{
  echo "Data set is not ready!<br>";
}
?>
```

and the result display on the browser:

```
192.168.0.108
Data set is not ready!
```

Comment: Might be a typo in your example, but you need `$_POST`, not `$_post`. PHP variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: Note: `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is the default form encoding, you don't have to write it into your HTML, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

Comment: If you don't mind, PLEASE STATE THE REASON WHY YOU VOTED DOWN,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST[]` is not a function but language construct used to **add** items into $_POST array.
While `$_POST` is a variable, though you are not using it anyway but whatever `$_post` variable instead.

Comment: really !! The problem is solved. I should use upper case for $_POST['_id'].  Thanks a lot !