# Issue with forms in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php $_POST array empty upon form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission)

I am trying to have a form filled out, then the data displayed on another page. The first document is this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="testerpage.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="testname">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The other page (testerpage.php) is this

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
echo $_POST["testname"];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Why won't testerpage display the information from the first page(named welcome.php)? It doesn't work with "get" either

Comment: What version of php are you using ???

Comment: try to type in address bar: `testerpage.php?testname=welcome`. Is it work?

Comment: @mario i think this may be different ..

Comment: @Baba It's not the reference I was looking for [...], there was a better debugging howto somewhere [...]

Comment: I have 5.4.7, and testname=welcome doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean `welcome doesn't work` ????? you see you can see anything on the page ?? use `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Comment: code looks good, check your server error log if you see any error,

Comment: There is absolutely nothing on the page... and where do I put var_dump($_REQUEST)? I'm new to php

Comment: This might sound weird, but what do you have in the field when you post it?

Comment: I have tried everything from my name, to numbers, to special characters, to profanity. None of it works

Comment: Can we see this page somehow? Do you have access to the server's error log?

Comment: I don't know, I am completely new to this. I have xampp 1.8.1, where would the error log be?

Comment: can you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_error", "On");` to the top of your page ..and tell me what you get

Comment: add this to welcome or testerpage?

Comment: Check source code of resulting HTML page. Maybe PHP is disabled and PHP code just is not executed. If so, you should see your PHP code inside HTML output.

Comment: When I view source code of testerpage I do see the php, and I know just enough that I shouldn't be able to.

Comment: What host are you using?

Comment: I just figured it out, I wasn't going to localhost/welcome.php, I was just running it from notepad++. It works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have untouched PHP code in your HTML output, it turns out PHP is disabled on your server so PHP code is not executed at all. Consult your hosting provider technical support on enabling PHP on server.