# No POST data received Symfony

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, post, production-environment

I am struggling with a strange problem since I'm on production on a mutualized server.
I have a firewall securing my admin panel matching all the url with /admin/*.

On this administration panel, all the POST data that I send do not arrive to the controller.

```
var_dump($this->get('request')->request->all())
```

gives me an empty array
, same thing for :

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

This is very annoying since all my forms and CRUD functionalities do not work anymore...
The other pages of my website (not on the admin panel) do work correctly.

The Chrome and FireBug console show me that the data is sent the right way.

I'm thinking of a problem with my .htaccess files :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have this file on my www directory to point to the web directory

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

And I've added this in the .htaccess of my web directory

My firewalls :

```
    firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  /login
            check_path:  /login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path:            /admin
            use_referer:                    true
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /login

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My PHP code of the controller function :

```
public function testAction() {
    return new Response(var_dump($_POST));
}
```

Simple HTML form :

```
<form action="{{path_for_controller}}" method="POST"/>
<input type="text" name="search"/>
<input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

Just $this->get('request')->get('search') gives me null and POST is also empty.

Thank you for your help, I'm really getting desperate ...

**EDIT**

I noticed that it worked a few times after clearing my cache but only for a moment

Comment: Exactly the same problem over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540085/symfony2-and-cross-site-post-request-empty-data

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing, at least I'm not the only one having this issue, I will keep you informed if I manage to find a solution.

Comment: Can you include your firewall rules as well?

Comment: Hi, I've added the firewall rules. Thanks for helping

Comment: Did you checked request history in symfony profiler? Maybe you have some redirect and that is the reason why your post data is empty.

Comment: Is there a way to enable the profiler on production environment ? The status code is 200 OK when sending POST data to a controller.

Comment: Hi, I have solved the issue that actually was a server configuration issue. You can see it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540085/symfony2-and-cross-site-post-request-empty-data

Comment: Hi David, I'm also on OVH, I removed the .ovhconfig at root but that didn't help. Could you tell me what you did with that file ? Thanks

Comment: I actually removed it, and set the SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4 in the .htaccess. Cleared the cache and it worked actually pretty good

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue some time ago. But my problem was redirection(rewrite). The form was being submitted to right URL but the rewrite was redirecting it to another location, and redirection dont carry along post data.

In chrome developer console, if you check `Preserve log`, then you will be able to see it.

I think in your case this is causing problems

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Best thing to setup Symfony2, I would say is , set your `DocumentRoot` to the `web` directory, than doing it through .htaccess

Comment: Hi, sorry for taking so much time to answer, I will try this tomorrow and let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I tried some configurations with my htaccess but none of them worked.
Also, The preserve logs didn't show me any redirections, looks like that was not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try `print_r($_GET)` in PHP on the page you're working on.

Comment: It gives me : Array ( ) 1

Comment: are the variables getting out through $_POST?

Comment: $_POST is always empty, on my controller I recieve a POST method request but no data. Chrome console show me the form data is being sent

Comment: How is the form handled?

Comment: Yes the array is empty.
Most of my data is sent with Ajax but even when I try a really simple form with just one input and a submit button, nothing in received on the controller's side

Comment: I would just test something really basic, to look inside $_POST. I've edited my first post

Comment: Where are the variables, and HTML in the program?

Comment: I have different forms in my application, but most of them are pretty basic, for example just a research input to filter my table of results. I've updated my first post to add it.