# $_FILES is null, $_POST is empty array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, file-upload

I am trying ajax file upload. I've tried the same script in another proect. It worked properly. But now its not working. On the server side I get 'Null' with `var_dump($_FILES["uploadFiles"]);` and 
`var_dump($_POST["uploadFiles"]);` returns an empty array: array(1) { [0]=>string(0)""}

So I suspect some issues with apache/php configuration.

One of the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission) discusses about htaccess redirect rules. Here is my htaccess content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress</code>
```

Is there any thing wrong with my htaccess content?

If not what else may be the reason for $_FILES to be Null?

My php.ini variables:

```
post_max_size = 160M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
upload_tmp_dir = "/tmp/"
file_uploads = On 
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Thanks in Advance for your help.

update:

Response headers of in browser:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
  <form class="inputF" id="entry_upload_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="field_text">
         Attach file:  
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="file1[]" id="file1"> <br>

        <div class="field_text">
         Attach file:  
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="file2[]" id="file2"> <br>

        <div class="field_text">
         Attach file:  
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="file3[]" id="file3"> <br>

        <div class="buttonRow">
          <button class="submit buttons greenButton">Post</button> 
          <button class="reset buttons blueButton">Reset</button>
        </div>
  </form>
```

part of my jQuery:

```
var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file1');
    files1 = fileSelect.files;

    if(files1.length != 0) {
        files[i] = fileSelect.files;
        i++;
    }

    fileSelect = document.getElementById('file2');
    files1 = fileSelect.files;

    if(files1.length != 0) {
        files[i] = fileSelect.files;
        i++;
    }

    fileSelect = document.getElementById('file3');
    files1 = fileSelect.files;

    if(files1.length != 0) {
        files[i] = fileSelect.files;
        i++;
    }

    // Create a new FormData object.
    var formData = new FormData();

    // Loop through each of the selected files.
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];

      // Add the file to the request.
      formData.append('uploadFiles[]', file, file.name);
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: content_url + '/themes/Karma/entry-portal/ajax_upload.php',  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
        beforeSend: function () {
                //jQuery("#wpboulevard_progressBar").show();
            },
        success: function (response) {
                //jQuery('#wpboulevard_upload_status').html(response);
            },
                //error: errorHandler,
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
//On success
    function completeHandler(){
        jQuery().html('Files uploaded successfully');
    }

    //Progress handling function
    function progressHandlingFunction(e){
        if(e.lengthComputable){
            jQuery('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No errors or warnings in logs?  /tmp folder accessible?  Here is a good check list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Tried `formData.append('uploadFiles', file);` instead of `formData.append('uploadFiles[]', file, file.name);` ? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @JayBlanchard I added the response from the browser's console. Seems to be ok.

Comment: 144 bytes and not seeing any request payload in your screen shot.  I'm thinking issue is client side JS related.

Comment: @guest271314 I tried your suggestion. $_FILES is null. But var_dump($_POST) shows this: string(17) "[object FileList]"

Comment: Agree with guest271314.  The method signature looks wrong for `append`.  Should be `formData.append(name, value, filename);`

Comment: @ficuscr I can check the variables file and files. They have the 'file' objects. But I dont know how to check whether formData is actually appended with uploaded files. Other than this not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Other than that nothing jumps out at me.  Suppose you could scrap it and look at something like http://www.plupload.com/ - Nice library and would get rid of that arbitrary 3 file inputs approach.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to use a library.

Comment: @Mr.code892 Try utitlizing `json` , `data-uri`s to process , upload files; see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<form class="inputF" id="entry_upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="field_text">Attach file:</div>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" id="myFiles" multiple> <br>

        <div class="buttonRow">
          <button class="submit buttons greenButton">Post</button> 
          <button class="reset buttons blueButton">Reset</button>
        </div>
  </form>
```

The HTML changes will allow the user to upload multiple files with only one file input. If you want to limit the user to 3 files only, you can do this on the client side with some javascript or you can do it on the server side with PHP. The user can hold down the `CTRL` or `Shift` key to select multiple files to upload at once.

Now change this part of your javascript/jQuery from this:

```
    var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file1');
    files1 = fileSelect.files;

    if(files1.length != 0) {
        files[i] = fileSelect.files;
        i++;
    }

    fileSelect = document.getElementById('file2');
    files1 = fileSelect.files;

    if(files1.length != 0) {
        files[i] = fileSelect.files;
        i++;
    }

    fileSelect = document.getElementById('file3');
    files1 = fileSelect.files;

    if(files1.length != 0) {
        files[i] = fileSelect.files;
        i++;
    }

    // Create a new FormData object.
    var formData = new FormData();

    // Loop through each of the selected files.
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];

      // Add the file to the request.
      formData.append('uploadFiles[]', file, file.name);
    }
```

**To This:**

```
var formData = new FormData();
// Loop through each file attached for upload and append it to formData
$.each($('#myFiles')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append('uploadFiles['+i+']', file);
});
```