# How can I write to a txt file from within an html form with an action?

Tags: php, html

Sorry if this is a repost, i didn't find an article that gives a solution to this issue.

Here's my example code:

```
<?php

echo "<form action=\"test2.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"ent1\">";

$queue = $_POST["ent1"];

$fh = fopen("temp.txt", 'w');
fwrite($fh, $queue);
fclose($fh);

echo "<input type=\"submit\">";

?>
```

This code should write whatever i type in the text box to the file "temp.txt" but it doesn't. It has something to do with the form action. It works fine if I take out the action and just use:

```
echo "<form method=\"post\">";
```

is there a way around this issue? I need to call an action when I click on my submit button and write to a file at the same time.

Comment: did you check whether this working??

Comment: is this file named as test2.php ?

Comment: Just a side note: You don't have to escape your quotation marks if you use single quotes when using `echo`, like `echo '<form action="test2.php" method="post">'`

Comment: it works without the "action" in the form. doesn't work with. 

when I click on the submit button, it opens test2.php which doesn't have anything to do with temp.txt. But it should be writing what i have in the text box to temp.txt and then open test2.php

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as `test2.php`

```
<?php

echo "<form action=\"test2.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"ent1\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\">";

if(isset($_POST["ent1"])){
    $queue = $_POST["ent1"];
    $fh = fopen("temp.txt", 'w');
    fwrite($fh, $queue);
    fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

Comment: test2.php and temp.txt are two different things. I'm using test2.php as a page on my website but temp.txt is just storing some information behind the website.. 

the code above works the same as the code I posted originally :/

Answer (score 0):

You should split your code in two files : the form, and the form's validation :

`test1.php`

```
<?php

echo '<form action="test2.php" method="post">'
    . '<input type="text" name="ent1">'
    . '<input type="submit">';
```

`test2.php`

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["ent1"]))
{
    $queue = $_POST["ent1"];
    //Some input validation code

    $fh = fopen("temp.txt", 'w');
    fwrite($fh, $queue);
    fclose($fh);
}
else
{
    //Some error handling code
}
```

Edit :

`test1.php`

```
<?php

echo '<form action="./test2.php" method="post">' //...
```

`test2.php`

```
<?php

//...
//$fh = fopen("temp.txt", 'w');
//fwrite($fh, $queue);
//fclose($fh);

/*Less calls here, do the same*/
file_put_contents("temp.txt", $queue);
//...
```

Comment: does that work for you? I'm still having the same problem.. works without action, doesn't work with D:

Comment: I just edited my post : i added a else, where you should write something like `echo 'ERROR';`, in order to debug your app

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? It dosen't write in the file when you add the `action` attribute in the `form` tag ?

Comment: yes exactly. it doesn't write to the file when my form has an action attribute.

Comment: Which is very strange. Hold on, i'm going to test something

Comment: Works for me. I put the two files in the same directory, and it writes in the `temp.txt` file in the same directory. Check the edits in my post

Comment: What version of php are you using?

I was messing around with thing and noticed that if I use a hard coded string like this: fwrite($fh, "SOME TEXT"); that it works, but not with a $variable. :S  so confused

Comment: Php 5.4. Can you try to `echo $queue` in the `if` before writing in the file, `echo 'NOPE'` in the `else`, re-run, and tell me if this pass ?

Comment: Then, your `$_POST["ent1"]` is not set. Replace `echo 'NOPE'` with `var_dump($_POST);`, and tell me what you get (if the array is empty or not)

Comment: Hmmm. Please check if you made no mistakes in the names, especially `ent1` , and make sure there is no redirection between `test1.php` and `test2.php`. If you have a redirection, then your $_POST could have been flushed

Comment: <?php

echo '<form action="test2.php" method="post">'
    . '<input type="text" name="ent1">'
    . '<input type="submit">';


if(isset($_POST["ent1"]))
{
    $queue = $_POST["ent1"];
    echo $queue;

    $fh = fopen("temp.txt", 'w');
    fwrite($fh, $queue);
    fclose($fh);
}
else
{
    var_dump($_POST);
}


that's the code i'm using to test right now. copied and pasted.

Comment: im going to stop for now. thanks for all your help Yoluk! you've been very helpful :)

Comment: I tried your code, works for me. I suggest you to check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission.
Good luck with this, it seems nasty. ;)