# $_POST array is empty even though file("php://input"); returns the values correctly

Tags: php, forms, post

**The issue:**

$_POST array is empty even though file("php://input"); returns the values correctly (see below)

**My form:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="loginform" method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Username</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" step="any" name="username" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" step="any" name="password" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>

<?php
$mypostdata = file("php://input");
print "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($mypostdata);
print "</pre>"
?>
```

**My output:**

> ```
> array(0) {
> }
> array(1) {
> [0]=>
> string(46) "username=aravind&password=secret&submit=Submit"
> }
> ```

Comment: Check the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I accessed the file by using PhpStorm (a third party application) the link it used was ("http://**localhost:63342**/emitest/loginform.php**") and $_POST didn't work.

When I accessed the file by typing link ("http://**localhost**/emitest/loginform.php") directly in browser, $_POST works.

So, directory/port is the problem and that is where $_POST loses data.

Answer (score -1):

Your php code is here executed regardless of the form.

You have to embrace it inside a if :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // i.e. if the submit button has been clicked
  $mypostdata = file("php://input");
  print "<pre>";
  var_dump($_POST);
  var_dump($mypostdata);
  print "</pre>"
}
?>
```

For more about forms with PHP : http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php or http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html