# PHP simple form not posting

Tags: php

I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure out why the isset($_POST['Submit']) is not executing with my form. The data from the form is just not passing into the php code. Basically the code does not seem to be recognizing something like $ffname = $_POST["ffname"];

```
<?php
$ffname = $flname = $femail = $fcemail = $fpass = $fcpass = "";
if(isset($_POST['ffname'])){
    $ffname = $_POST["ffname"];
    $flname = $_POST["flname"];
    $femail = $_POST["femail"];
    $fcemail = $_POST["fcemail"];
    $fpass = $_POST["fpass"];
    $fcpass = $_POST["fcpass"];
    echo "<p>Hello World<p>";
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($con, "userdata") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbluser (fname, lname, email, pass) VALUES('$ffname', '$flname', '$femail', '$fpass')")
    or die (mysqli_error($con));
}

?>


<form method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="ffname" id="ffname" value="<?php echo $ffname;?>"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="flname" value="<?php echo $flname;?>"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="femail" value="<?php echo $femail;?>"><br>
    Confirm E-mail: <input type="email" name="fcemail" value="<?php echo $fcemail;?>"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="fpass" value="<?php echo $fpass;?>"><br>
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="fcpass" value="<?php echo $fcpass;?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Name the submit: name='Submit'

Comment: Try and remove the space between `<input type="text" name="ffname" ....`

Comment: What space? I tried removing the spaces between type, name .. but nothing happened.

Comment: If this is the latest version of your code, based on answers below, then you haven't done all of the things suggested.  Please try all things suggested, and post THAT code that "doesn't work".  (Removing form action, watch `$_POST['ffname']`.

Comment: Look at your browser's inspector tools' network tab and check out the details of the actual HTTP request that is being made. Are all the parameters posted as expected? Is the request redirected somehow?

Comment: @cale_b Okay, this is with everything you suggested. It does not work.

Comment: @deceze Well, the form data is correct. I'm not sure if that means anything.

Comment: I don't know. What *does* it mean? Did you have a look at your Web Inspector of choice? (Ctrl+Alt+C, or something similar, on Chrome, Safari and Firefox)

Comment: @deceze Yes, the network tab says it was a POST request with the correct form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer by @DerVO is correct.  **But** there seems to be something else at play, since you say it still doesn't work.

A comment became too long, so I've built a full answer here.

**Step 1:**
Add a name to your input:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
```

However, relying on the submit in your `$_POST` is not the best plan.  So I suggest watching a different form field - for example, `ffname`:

**Step 2:**
Improve your watch, using a different field:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['ffname'] ) ) {
    // do your work
}
```

Lastly, you may be munging your form `action` attribute.

**Step 3:**
In order to keep things simple, if the form is supposed to submit to the same page, you can simply omit the form `action`.

```
<form method="post">
```

Betweeen these three items, the form will work, unless you have some problem with your server.

**Step 4:**

Clean up your form formatting.  You've got odd spacing which is problematic.  In an html element, the `property="value"` code needs to be without spaces, but spaces between properties.  Example:

```
<!-- Your version -->
<input type = "text"name = "ffname"id = "ffname"value="<?php echo $ffname;?>"><br>
<!-- Clean / correct version -->
<input type="text" name="ffname" id="ffname" value="<?php echo $ffname;?>"><br>
```

Here's a "clean" version of your whole form:

```
<form method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="ffname" id="ffname" value="<?php echo $ffname;?>"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="flname" value="<?php echo $flname;?>"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="femail" value="<?php echo $femail;?>"><br>
    Confirm E-mail: <input type="email" name="fcemail" value="<?php echo $fcemail;?>"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="fpass" value="<?php echo $fpass;?>"><br>
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="fcpass" value="<?php echo $fcpass;?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Okay, I tried all three things. That must mean there is something wrong with my server?

Comment: Edit your question with the latest version of the code you are using, please.  That's the ONLY way we can help, and be sure some other error isn't introduced.

Comment: Well that's just weird.  What kind of computer are you using? What browser?

Comment: I am using a Macbook Pro with Bootcamp on Windows 10 and Google Chrome. I don't know if it helps but I'm also using PHP 7 with WAMP. Also using phpstorm to edit this. Also on university wifi, maybe something with that?

Comment: At this point, I'd recommend you review [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1282909/870729), all the answers, **including reading the comments**.  There's a variety of good stuff in there, and your code at this point should be working.

Comment: All right I took a look. Thanks for your help but I guess I will have to try this on another PC.

Comment: It seems it was a problem with my PC. I ran it on a different one and everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your input submit a name:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: As a side-note to the OP, the name `Submit` is a lousy name.  Very ambiguous, and could be something more useful.

Comment: I agree @cale_b. I also suggest not to rely on the submit button at all (I remember a problem with IE6 and sending the form via pressing `Enter`). Use a hidden input to check, if the form was submitted.

Comment: @Arie It should work. Can you add a `var_dump($_POST)` to your code and look what the output is?

Comment: @DerVO It says array(0) { }

Comment: @Aire Even if you hit your Submit button?

Comment: @DerVO Yes even when I hit it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107140/discussion-between-aire-and-dervo).

Answer (score 1):

You have pass name of element in $_POST

try put name attribute in input submit

```
<input type = "submit" name="Submit" value = "1">
```