# OkHttp POST Does Not Seem to Send Request Body

Tags: php, android, post, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to use `RetroFit2` and `OkHttp3` to do a POST method on a PHP script. I have been doing GET methods perfectly fine, but I have been having problems with posting.

I have an `HttpLoggingInterceptor` set up with my `OkHttpClient`, and it logs the request body perfectly. But my PHP script was not receiving the data, so I tried just outputting the `$_POST` data as soon as I got it, but it is an empty string. I cannot tell if there is something wrong on the Android side, the server side, or both.

My `RetroFit` object and `OkHttpClient` are set up like so:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cookieJar(RestCookieJar.getInstance())
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .build();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .registerTypeAdapter(Instant.class, new InstantAdapter())
        .registerTypeAdapter(LatLng.class, new LatLngAdapter())
        .registerTypeAdapter(Uri.class, new UriAdapter())
        .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(client)
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build();

RestService service = retrofit.create(RestService.class);
```

Then my `RestService` interface is set up like this:

```
public interface RestService {

    @GET("api/index.php")
    Call<List<Session>> getSessions();

    @POST("api/index.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> postSession(@Body Session session);
}
```

As I mentioned, this all *seems* to work, but when I call:

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        print_r($_POST);
    }
```

I get an empty set of parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer here: [php $_POST array empty upon form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14794856/5115932). Retrofit automatically sets the `Content-Type` to `"application/json; charset=UTF-8"`, which in PHP versions 5.0 - 5.19, there is a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63947&edit=2) causing the request body to not be parsed into the `$_POST` variable. The server I am using is running PHP 5.10 (which I have no control over).

The workaround for this bug is to parse the JSON data yourself from the raw request body:

```
if($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] === 'application/json; charset=UTF-8') {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
}
```