# PHP - POST is not catching any value, where GET works well

Tags: php

**SORRY FRIENDS FOR THIS QUESTION, I TESTED THE SAME CODE IN REAL TIME SERVER. IT WORKED FINE, BUT WHEN THE CODE RETURN IN PHPSTORM IT NOT WORKED.**
(don't know exactly what the reason )

**First.php**

```
<form action="second.php" method="post" >
    Name: <input  type="text" name="name" >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    $username = $_POST["name"];
    echo $username;
}else
{
    echo "null value";
}
?>
```

Here i am getting null value. 
dont know what the reson.

---

but i simple testing this will GET (where method="get")
and 
**second.php** is

```
<?php
echo $_GET["name"];
?>
```

it worked well.

Comment: That code seems to work for me? Is error reporting enabled and showing anything?

Comment: What just `echo var_dump($_POST);` gives you?

Comment: That sounds strange..  have you tried to print_r($_POST); in second.php ?

Comment: What if you add `isset` check on submit button (add the name property to it)?

Comment: This code is working for me

Comment: Have you written correct `action` in form tag

Comment: check $_request for above

Comment: Your code works for me.  Maybe a PHP config issue?  [Some ideas here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission)

Comment: @Script47, sorry friends, just now tested in real time server it worked fine, but when i tested in phpStorm its not working

Comment: @Don'tPanic sorry friends, just now tested in real time server it worked fine, but when i tested in phpStorm its not working

Comment: @bhv  does your first.php correctly firing a post request on submit ?.

Comment: @RanjanaLK . yeah it working fine.. but in second.php post is not getting any value.. ( i just tested the same code in other server its worked fine. bu t when i write this code using phpStorm in localhost it not working )

Comment: @bhv can you show me the submit request you see on firebug when you are on localhost

Comment: @RanjanaLK don't have much knowledge in firebug.  is this what you asked me ->    body > form > input[type="submit"]:nth-child(2)

Comment: open first.php on you browser ,open firebug, go to net tab on firebug, then hit the submit button. now you can see the request that came to second.php. if you see a `POST second.php` as the url you have no problem with the request. but if you see `GET second.php?name=something` then you have a problem with your request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121448/discussion-between-ranjanalk-and-bhv).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<form action="second.php" method="post" >
Name: <input  type="text" name="name" >
<input type="submit">
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $username = $_POST["name"];
    echo $username;
}else
{
    echo "null value";
}
?>
```

Comment: His php code is in `second.php`. Why would he let the form post to the same page? Either way, this wont make a difference.

Comment: It wont be any difference

Comment: I have also added `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` instead of `POST`

Comment: I was waiting for his response but he didn't replied anything