# Avoid Angular 2 and PHP cross-domain communication in the same computer

Tags: php, angular, request, cross-domain

I'm developing a webapp and I'm using Angunlar 2 as my frontend framework and CodeIgniter 3 as my backend framework. I use Angular-CLI, so my Angular app runs on port 4200, while my "server-side" works on port 80.

So, when I try to do a post request from Angular to PHP, I'm making a cross-domain request, because of the different ports. I checked it in the Network tabs of Chrome, I see the two request done (one for options and one for the post itself).

The problem that I have is that I can't figure out to receive the post body (I have changed the Content-Lenght to in my header and is always on runtime).

The headers I have configured are:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
```

The question is: is there a way to avoid the cross-domain here? Naturally, I have tryed to start the serve in port 80, but it is busy. And if there is not a way to avoid the cross-domain, could someone please give me and idea of how to continue working with this?

Thanks

Comment: I have to mention thtat I don't have problems with get request, the problem that I have is with the post request and the problem is that I don't receive anything in the body (the content-lenght is 2 and I can't change it)

Comment: For those who have the same problem, the solution that @Raiper34 wrote is perfect. If you still having problems, maybe is because the $_POST array is not populating. The solution to this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14794856/3368457

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run "google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir" or ude this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi , because server side settings is not enought, you need to send modified api calls too.

Comment: Perfect! I tryed it and I can do the requests as if they are in the same domain

Comment: Althought, I still not receiving the body of the request. I try in the server-side this: `echo json_encode($_POST]);` to see if I receive something but nothing...

Comment: do you mean on server side?

Comment: Yes. I did that to check if I receive something but still nothing

Comment: And did you see, that data was send in Chrome developer console?

Comment: Yes, the data is sent, I see the request payload correctly

Comment: Try it only with this line: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Comment: The only thing I can think is wrong is the content-length header, the server-side is always 4 and naturaly, the client-side depends on the data. I have tryed to set it but no lucky

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147842/discussion-between-user3368457-and-raiper34).