# PHP & MySQL - Undefined index: VIN when trying to do a small query using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using a book to learn some PHP and MySQL and I'm trying to introduce things from an HTML form to a mysql DB and I don't really get what is happening.

HTML

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Joy of PHP</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Sam's Used Cars
</h1>
<form action="SubmitCarReader.php" method="post">
 VIN: <input name="VIN" type="text" /><br />
 <br />
 Make: <input name="Make" type="text" /><br />
 <br />
 Model: <input name="Model" type="text" /><br />
 <br />
 Price: <input name="Asking_Price" type="text" /><br />
 <br />
 <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" /><br />
 &nbsp;</form>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Car saved</title>
</head>
<?php

$VIN = $_POST['VIN'];
$Make = $_POST['Make'];
$Model = $_POST['Model'];
$Price = $_POST['Asking_Price'];

$query = "INSERT INTO Masini_table
(VIN, Make, Model,Asking_Price)
VALUES( 
'$VIN',
'$Make',
'$Model',
$Price
)";

echo($query);

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'masini');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("connect failed", mysqli_connect_error());
  die();
}
echo("connected <br>");
$mysqli->select_db("masini");
echo("selected <br>");
if($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
  echo("introduced $Make $Model <br>");
}
else 
{
echo("did not introduce $VIN  <br>"); 
}
$mysqli->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Xampp.

Errors:

```html
Notice: Undefined index: VIN in C:\xampp\htdocs\SubmitCarReader.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: Make in C:\xampp\htdocs\SubmitCarReader.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: Model in C:\xampp\htdocs\SubmitCarReader.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: Asking_Price in C:\xampp\htdocs\SubmitCarReader.php on line 10
INSERT INTO Masini_table (VIN, Make, Model,Asking_Price) VALUES( '', '', '', )connected
```

I also find odd introducing $Price in the query without the '' like '$VIN' by example but I tried it both ways and it still does not work.

I'm also a beginner in PHP and MySQL so if I'm missing something important it would be really nice for you to explain it to me.
Thanks.

Comment: As I see that your code has injection vulnerabilities https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp I doubt this book is up to date. Look into prepared statements and look up some more recent tutorials.

Comment: Nah it's not. I will but right now I tried to get the basics with this. It's from 2012 I think.

Comment: The undefined index error indicates that your `$_POST` array is empty, or missing these indexes.  Add this to your PHP page: `print_r($_POST);` to see it's content in full.

Comment: It returns "Array ( )".

Comment: This hasn't much to do with basics, a PHP book from 2012 will have other conventions, code structure and as you see very outdated functions/practices. PHP as changed a lot since 2012 so I really recommend ignoring that book and looking up good recent tutorial. And if it's really only about the basics, I'd suggest you start at codecademy.

Comment: Then can you recommend me a book which would help me?

Comment: use  `if (isset($_POST['value']))` to check

Comment: Bizarre, I cut and past your HTML page and made SubmitCarReader.php to contain just `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` and it works, I do get the values in $_POST.  Detail I noticed, in your PHP page, you have no `<body>`, but that is not causing the original issue...  You do type in some values in the HTML form before submitting right?

Comment: @Nic3500 so you still get no idea?

Comment: @AhmedSunny so it does not work. <?php if (isset($_POST['VIN']))
{
echo("b");
}
?> doesn't print anything

Comment: @AndreiDaniel: taken that the code you use is what is posted here, that you do type some test values in the form fields, no I do not understand.  If your $_POST is empty, obviously nothing else will work.  Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission they do have some suggestions (like parameter enable_post_data_reading) and others...

Answer (score 0):

Hi Change your code as like below

```
<?php
if($_POST['Submit1'])
{
$VIN = $_POST['VIN'];
$Make = $_POST['Make'];
$Model = $_POST['Model'];
$Price = $_POST['Asking_Price'];

$query = "INSERT INTO Masini_table
(VIN, Make, Model,Asking_Price)
VALUES( 
'$VIN',
'$Make',
'$Model',
$Price
)";

echo($query);
}

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'masini');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("connect failed", mysqli_connect_error());
 die();
}
echo("connected <br>");
$mysqli->select_db("masini");
echo("selected <br>");
if($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
 echo("introduced $Make $Model <br>");
}
else 
{
echo("did not introduce $VIN  <br>");   
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```