# PHP not populating $_POST when using x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: php, forms, content-type

PHP 5.4.17

I have a simple html form that looks something like this:

### index.html

```
<form method="POST" action="/addnewaccount.php">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### addnewaccount.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST); // array(0) {}
var_dump($_REQUEST); // array(0) {}
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')); //string(0) ""
var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); // NULL
```

When this form gets submitted, php will not populate the $_POST or $_REQUEST variables. They are just empty arrays.

I have checked the following in my php.ini file:

```
enable_post_data_reading = On
post_max_size = 10M
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
```

If I change the form's enctype to "multipart/form-data", the $_POST and $_REQUEST variables are populated, so I feel that the issue is with the default enctype of "x-www-form-urlencoded", but I can't figure out how to get things to work with the default.

Comment: Is `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` outputting any content? If no then most I would check if there is no special configuration in your webserver which limits this. Also: do you maybe have `suhosin` installed? Check this by printing out your `phpinfo();` (better than checking `php.ini` in case you missed somewhere loading of additional modules).

Comment: Did you check the answers of this question: [php $_POST array empty upon form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission) your case could be one of them.

Comment: Thank you @BartoszPachołek. Because I am not posting JSON, php://input is just an empty string.

Comment: Thank you @Accountantم, I have reviewed the answers in that other StackOverflow question and none of them have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. I discovered that it was an interaction of our Node proxy and php.

In our Node code, we were using the 'body-parser' npm package. We had a line where we were using the middleware for form-data like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

That middleware converted the form data to JSON before the request was proxied which prevented PHP from getting the data.

Hopefully this helps someone who might have a similar situation in the future.