# file_get_contents('php://input') Returns empty for one user, but works fine for others

Tags: javascript, php, post

Having a very strange issue with my web server. My server shows an empty string for file_get_contents('php://input'), but for only one user. It works fine for me and a few others but one specific user cannot use anything on the site that uses POST requests because the server is just receiving no POST information from his browsers, on his PC. However it also works fine on his phone. It's even more difficult to test because I cannot replicate it myself, it is working fine for me. I've had him try multiple different browsers and incognito incase it was some weird setting in Chrome that was breaking it for him but nothing seems to be working. I've checked in the headers in his chrome tools and it seems like all of the information is there, but the server still sees nothing.
The code I'm using is pretty straightforward, just using fetch to send a post request

```
 let fetchCheckoutID = fetch("stripe/createcustomcheckout.php", {
  credentials: 'include',
  method: "POST",
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    currency: customCheckoutCurrency.value.toLowerCase(),
    price: customCheckoutValue.value,
    name: customCheckoutName.value
  })
}).then(function (response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(async function (session) {
  stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id});
}).then(function (result) {

  if(result.error) {
    alert(result.error.message);
  }
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error("Stripe Setup: ", error);
});
```

And then on the server side

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

This is just the code that I discovered the issue with, none of the POST requests on the entire website are working for him specifically, but are fine for everyone else. I've spent like the last 4 hours with him trying to figure this out, since it has been working fine for him for months and now suddenly he basically cannot use the site since so much of it relies on POST requests to the server. And if this is an issue that he can get then surely other users could have the same issue...
I'm not sure where else to go, I cannot find any other posts that are having the same issue. I just find a ton of people who can't find information in $_POST and people recommend they use file_get_input() just like was already using. I've tried a lot of fixes people recommended anyway, even though the issues weren't the exact same but nothing has worked so far.

Here is some information from inside his browser, with some information censored.

His request headers:

```
Request URL: ///stripe/createcustomcheckout.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: ///
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 22:17:42 GMT
host-header: 8441280b0c35cbc114
server: nginx
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-httpd: 1
x-proxy-cache-info: DT:1
:authority: ///
:method: POST
:path: /stripe/createcustomcheckout.php
:scheme: https
accept: /
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 49
content-type: application/json
cookie: stripe_mid=499cb16f-aea1-4724-b6f7-ef968c5733696ba34;                 
stripe_sid=f2bbde34-9dab-4f3f-9dfc-bb2904e813a1716c2
origin: ///.com/
referer: ///createstripe
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91",                 
"Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)     
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 
Safari/537.36
{currency: "usd", price: "21", name: "ertrgdfg"}
currency: "usd"
name: "ertrgdfg"
price: "21"
```

And this is the server response, I have it var_dumping the entirety of $_SERVER, and the empty string at the bottom is a var_dump of the $json variable from earlier (the empty php://input).

```
["PATH"]=>
string(28) "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
string(52) "///.com/public_html"
["HTTPS"]=>
string(2) "on"
["UNIQUE_ID"]=>
string(27) "YPdK0LJppGoU///AAAAw"
["SCRIPT_URL"]=>
string(36) "/stripe/createcustomcheckout.php"
["SCRIPT_URI"]=>
string(57) "///stripe/createcustomcheckout.php"
["PHPHANDLER"]=>
string(24) "/usr/local/php74/bin/php"
["HTTP_X_PORT"]=>
string(4) "1033"
["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"]=>
string(14) "///"
["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"]=>
string(5) "https"
["HTTP_HOST"]=>
string(13) "///.com"
["HTTP_X_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=>
string(17) "gzip, deflate, br"
["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=>
string(5) "close"
["HTTP_SEC_CH_UA"]=>
string(64) "" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", 
"Chromium";v="91""
["HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE"]=>
string(2) "?0"
["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
string(115) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 
Safari/537.36"
["CONTENT_TYPE"]=>
string(16) "application/json"
["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
string(3) "*/*"
["HTTP_ORIGIN"]=>
string(21) "///.com"
["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE"]=>
string(11) "same-origin"
["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE"]=>
string(4) "cors"
["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST"]=>
string(5) "empty"
["HTTP_REFERER"]=>
string(38) "///createstripe"
["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=>
string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.9"
["HTTP_COOKIE"]=>
string(112) "__stripe_mid=499cb16f-aea1-4724-b6f7-ef933696ba34; 
__stripe_sid=f2bbde34-9dab-4f3f-9dfc-bb23a1716c2"
["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
string(6) "Apache"
["SERVER_NAME"]=>
string(13) "///.com"
["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
string(14) "///"
["SERVER_PORT"]=>
string(3) "443"
["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
string(14) "///"
["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
string(9) "webmaster"
["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
string(88) "///stripe/createcustomcheckout.php"
["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
string(5) "37988"
["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
string(7) "CGI/1.1"
["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
string(8) "HTTP/1.0"
["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
string(4) "POST"
["QUERY_STRING"]=>
string(0) ""
["REQUEST_URI"]=>
string(36) "/stripe/createcustomcheckout.php"
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
string(36) "/stripe/createcustomcheckout.php"
["PHP_DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT"]=>
string(2) "40"
["PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME"]=>
string(3) "120"
["PHP_MAX_INPUT_TIME"]=>
string(3) "120"
["PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT"]=>
string(4) "768M"
["PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE"]=>
string(4) "256M"
["PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE"]=>
string(4) "256M"
["PHP_SELF"]=>
string(36) "/stripe/createcustomcheckout.php"
["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=>
float(1626819280.5109)
["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
int(1626819280) 
}
string(0) ""
```

What I noticed is that the $_SERVER response from his request is lacking a ["CONTENT-LENGTH"] variable, which MY response has. However his request headers in his browser DO have a content-length, and the content is right there, but the server still sees nothing. I'm really stuck here and can't figure out why the server is not receiving his POST content. This isn't a random user this is the owner of the site (I'm just the developer), it's very important that he is able to use it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect he's going through a proxy that's breaking it.

Comment: Its not your code. Check his settings like proxy etc.

Comment: See I thought that could be the issue for a moment but he's only having the problem on this site. Every other site works fine. Also it's happening in multiple broswers so it's not like a chrome proxy setting or something.

Comment: `$json = urldecode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` — The data is JSON encoded, **not** URL encoded. Why are you passing it through `urldecode`?

Comment: You need to example the outgoing request body in the browser's developer tools, and the raw request body that PHP receives and then debug from there. That will at least narrow it down to "something going wrong in the browser" and "something going wrong between the browser an the PHP"

Comment: Oh, that's something I forgot to remove. I was just testing a ton of stuff trying to figure out what could be causing this. Thanks  for pointing it out I'll remove it now.

Comment: s/example/examine/

Comment: FYI, your `.then()` callback with the stripe redirect doesn't return anything so the next `.then()` won't receive any data in its `result` parameter

Comment: Ah, good eye. I'll fix that.

Comment: Cookie is sensitive information, don't forget to hide it!!!

Comment: I removed random characters from the cookies just in case

Comment: I don't have an answer, but in case it helps: PHP will only parse out the request and set up `$_POST` when content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded (standard html form) or multipart/form-data. For other content types, or for POSTs made with JS, data could be anything (eg JSON), and PHP has no way to parse that to construct a `$_POST` array - so it won't, and`$_POST` is not set.  Hence you need to read the raw data with `file_get_contents('php://input')`.  Conversely, `php://input` is not available with multipart/form-data.  Have you checked the request headers etc in devtools?

Comment: Could it be something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1631999?  Or maybe http -> https redirect, and that user is somehow always using http? Or different DNS meaning that user always ends up at www or non-www, where you don't?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for the suggestions. I created a test page for him to try to clarify where the problem may be coming from, and I tested a few things you suggested, but it mostly just reiterated what I already thought I understood. The test page tested 4 http requests. 1 GET via fetch, 2 POST via fetch and a POST via XMLHttpRequest. The GET request returned information like normal. But all 3 POST requests returned that there was no body. 1 POST fetch was content-type application/json, and the server tried to read it through php://input. Other POST fetch was application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @Don'tPanic the second POST fetch was read on the server through $_POST since the content type allowed. Still nothing. The 3rd POST via XMLHttpRequest was done with content type application/json, and there was still no POST body. Note that all of these methods worked properly on my system. I got the correct response every single time. I also checked the response.redirected header and they were false for both me and him. From all of what I can tell it is properly going through https every time, and not redirecting him. How else could POST information get lost other than redirecting?

Comment: Also the links to the endpoints in the JS are relative, so there shouldn't be a way for the https or www to change. But I went ahead and printed out the ResponseURL from the XMLHttpRequest anyway, and it looks normal. But that can also be seen in the Response Headers (Which I checked previously, and determined it wasn't that)

Comment: I'm not sure if you have access to his machine, probably not.  It would be good to get data on what the client (I mean browser, not person :-)) is doing, directly from the client, eg in devtools.  On the network tab, with "preserve log" and "disable cache" both ticked, you can verify (or not) what you are seeing on the back end, any redirects will be clear, clicking on a request will show if the fields were really POSTed from the client at all, etc.  I realise it might be hard to talk someone through investigating that remotely, but that would be what I would try to investigate next.

Comment: I just realised [you can export/import HAR files which from devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-76/#HAR) which would allow you to see everything from his machine.

Comment: Oh that's awesome I'll give that a go. I had him copy and paste his response headers from the network tab for me (I put them in the original post) but I'll try out the HAR files tomorrow. Being able to just look at everything myself will be a godsend.

Comment: Hey @Don'tPanic, Sorry to bring you back here again but you've been super helpful so far. I did what you suggested and had him send me his HAR file. I also had a friend (whose POST is working properly) send me their HAR file, and I compared them. There was only a single difference I could find, and that is that his cache-control header was missing. So I manually added a cache-control: no-cache header to one request, since that was the header that me and my friend had. However there is still no POST body. Do you know of anything else I should look for? Any PHP settings that could cause this?

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions I'm afraid, my hunch was something would turn up in the devtools network trace.  Maybe firewall, or anti-virus or something on his machine, messing with POSTs for some reason?  Or proxy as previously suggested, though I assume you've already checked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so I figured out the issue, incase anyone runs into this issue in the future.
I went to spend more time trying to Bugfix this issue today and the user was getting a new error, this time an entire error page response from my hosting service, outside of my control. This error said:

"The page you are trying to access is restricted due to a security rule. If you believe that this security rule is affecting the normal operation of your website, contact your hosting provider with detailed instructions how to recreate this error."

I use Siteground to host my website, so I contacted them to attempt to resolve this issue. Long story short they have a specific security rule on their backend that has issues with Bitdefender, and it was now blocking him. The support agent had to unblock his IP and he uninstalled Bitdefender and now everything is working fine. Bitdefender was blocking his POST requests for some reason. I don't really understand why and the support agent that I talked to couldn't tell me why but just try to uninstall/disable your Bitdefender, and if you're getting blocked with a security rule contact your hosting provider and see if they've blocked the IP.

Comment: I can confirm Bitdefender was causing the same issue for me, couldn't find any workaround other than pausing the protection if you really need to access the website, it's mainly blocking login attempts across different websites