# HTTP POST is empty

Tags: php, http

In 20 years of web development this one issue is near the top of the "Am I insane?" leader board.

I have a user on Firefox/Edge, with an ISP in germany, default internet setup, whenever he submits a form via POST, the $_POST var is empty. If I submit it, its fine.

I wrote a minimal code sample to verify this.

```php
<form action="/test.php?submit=1" method="post">
Test formular
<input type="text" name="line" value="test text"><br>
<input type="submit" name="Absenden" value="Absenden">
</form>
<br><br><hr>
<?php

if (!empty($_GET['submit'])) {
    $line = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " - " . date("d.m.y H:i:s") . "\r\n";
    $line .= "Contents of $_POST";
    $line .= "\r\n";
    $line .= print_r($_POST, true);
    $line .= "\r\n";
    $fp = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    fwrite($fp, $line);
    fclose($fp);
    
    echo "ok abgesendet";
}
```

Said user gets this logged:

```
[ip removed] - 30.07.21 12:06:40
Contents of Array
Array
(
)
```

I get this:

```
[ip removed] - 30.07.21 13:01:52
Contents of Array
Array
(
    [line] => test text
    [Absenden] => Absenden
)
```

This script is uploaded onto DomainFactory shared web hosting. Interestingly this script seems to work under one subdomain, but not the other. For me it works on either domain. How is this possible?

I watched said user submit this form via TeamViewer and checked in the dev console, the post vars are being sent by the browser.

[Edit:] I got more info. It seems it works under http, but not under https.

Comment: It can happen due to anti-virus or firewall, eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68450092/file-get-contentsphp-input-returns-empty-for-one-user-but-works-fine-for. But since you are generating that output based only on `$_GET` it means the user could generate that log out put just by doing a GET request ... maybe try logging the whole `$_SERVER` for more info?