# PHP $_POST returns empty only on one PC

Tags: php, post

I have a simple form in my PHP project using POST method to send data. Everything works well on the most computers, but there is a strange problem on only one of them.
Imagine that this is my simple form:

```
<form action="controller/save.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="username">
   <input type="submit" value="show">
</form>
```

And this is my PHP file:

```
<?php  
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

In all cases, it returns an array containing the value of username variable. But only on one case, it returns

```
Array()
```

I have been never seen such behavior and unfortunately couldn't understand what is the issue. May you help me please?

Comment: If the problem is only present from one particular client, then the issue is specific to their environment. Check for browser (and extensions) and any configured proxies

Comment: I tested it on multiple browsers, even in restricted modes like Incognito. I did not change anything!

Comment: And did you check the OS's proxy configuration?

Comment: There is no special configuration for proxy on that machine.

Comment: You'll need to do more debugging. Try `var_dump($_SERVER);`. Make sure it's a POST request

Comment: It is POST as I was receiving the exact results on other machines. However, I put your code and this was the result: `["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(4) "POST"` on all machines.

Comment: can you try to use post man and make a post to it

Comment: Can you use the browser dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the request and specifically, the Form Data? You might also need to run something like Wireshark to check the request at a lower level. There's very little anyone here can do to help you with this one

Comment: also try dumping $_REQUEST see if you see it in there

Comment: You may also `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));` The input stream contains the raw request body. If this is empty, you have a client side problem, if there is data, you have server side problem.

Comment: It can happen bcs of firewall/antivirus, see eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68450092/file-get-contentsphp-input-returns-empty-for-one-user-but-works-fine-for

Comment: @dMd, I can not use post man as it needs an active SESSION. In addition, the result of $_REQUEST was the same as $_POST `Array()`

Comment: @DB it was the result `string(0) ""`